# Scrapy / Python Modifying extracted data before saving?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to append a url to an extracted piece of data but cannot for the life of me find out how.

The selector i'm using is as follow:

'15_urlmod': response.url.split('=')[-1] + "_l_a1.jpg",

this line of code returns something like:

12306116_l_a1.jpg

what i then want to to is append http:exampleurl.com/images/12306116_l_a1.jpg

so the final url to be extracted and saved by scrapy would be:

http:exampleurl.com/images/12306116_l_a1.jpg

I'm new to Python and have searched for days trying to figure this out. the spider code i'm using is below in full:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector


    #Starting URL to scrape
class examplespiderscraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "examplespider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.exampleurl.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for book_url in response.xpath(
                "//div[@class='s-producttext-top-wrapper']/a//@href").extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(book_url), callback=self.parse_details)
        next_page = response.css('span.PageNumberInner > a.swipeNextClick::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)



    def parse_details(self, response):
        yield {
            '01_brand': response.xpath("//span[@id='lblProductBrand']/text()").extract_first(),
            '15_urlmod': response.url.split('=')[-1] + "_l_a1.jpg",
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, after having a little play around i came up with:

"https://sampleurl" + response.url.split('=')[-1] + "_l_a8.jpg"

never knew you could do that.

hope this helps someone else!